# how to merge 3 rows with the same data except 1 column?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

my output is look like:

| id order | status | item | supplier | confirm date | customer | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 555222 | approved | 12421 | Hawi | 12/02/2023 | 0122 | George |
| 555222 | approved | 12421 | Hawi | 12/02/2023 | 0122 | Michael |
| 555222 | approved | 12421 | Hawi | 12/02/2023 | 0122 | Tom |
| 543677 | approved | 85332 | Mint | 27/01/2023 | 0324 | John |
| 200013 | approved | 90210 | Mint | 27/01/2023 | 0714 | Brad |
| 111111 | approved | 80765 | Sweet | 11/01/2023 | 0122 | George |
| 111111 | approved | 80765 | Sweet | 11/01/2023 | 0122 | Michael |
| 111111 | approved | 80765 | Sweet | 11/01/2023 | 0122 | Tom |

I was trying to merge all the managers of customer 0122 in one row by using group_concat and seperate, but i got struggle with the "group by" because i have more fields in the select (like 78 columns in the output).
i want to know if there is any way my query can use the "where" clause for searching all my customers if they have more then 1 manager and if there is, the query will do something to merge them?
***the manager column and the customer column are coming from different tables.
for example the output i would like to get:

| id order | status | item | supplier | confirm date | customer | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 555222 | approved | 12421 | Hawi | 12/02/2023 | 0122 | George, Michael, Tom |
| 543677 | approved | 85332 | Mint | 27/01/2023 | 0324 | John |
| 200013 | approved | 90210 | Mint | 27/01/2023 | 0714 | Brad |
| 111111 | approved | 80765 | Sweet | 11/01/2023 | 0122 | George, Michael, Tom |

Comment: Please add the `CREATE TABLE` statements of the relevant tables to your question.

Answer (score 0):

use group_concat() by using the group columns and take it 1st cte then in another select the rest of yours 72 columns and join with the 1st cte
so sudo code will be like below

```
with cte as (
    select idorder,status,item,supplier,confirmdate,customer,group_concat(manager)
    from table_name
    group by idorder,status,item,supplier,confirmdate,customer
),  select yours other column from table_name a join cte b on a.col1=b.col1 ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your are joining to customer and manager data somehow. So, you could `GROUP BY` the customer in a subquery before joining the subquery to your orders.

This is a crude example, assuming that orders, customers and customer_managers come from different tables:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM orders o
JOIN (
    SELECT c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(cm.manager SEPARATOR ', ') AS managers
    FROM customers c
    JOIN customer_managers cm
        ON c.id = cm.customer_id
    GROUP BY c.id
) cust
    ON o.customer_id = cust.id;
```

If you have a vast number of customers and do not want to pre-aggregate the data for all of them, you could make the JOIN [LATERAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM orders o
JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(cm.manager SEPARATOR ', ') AS managers
    FROM customers c
    JOIN customer_managers cm
        ON c.id = cm.customer_id
    WHERE c.id = o.customer_id
    GROUP BY c.id
) cust;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3VbU3hZr)

Hopefully, this serves as an example of how to apply it to your data.

Comment: i tried to do the first query you suggested but i got back this out put:
customer | manager  
0122        | George, Michael, Tom, George, Michael, Tom, George, Michael, Tom.      

I mean I got the names of the managers as the amount time it appears in the table, instead off make it as one character

Comment: If you cannot figure it out for yourself, then you need to add the requested details to your question. DDL and sample data for orders, order_items, customers and customer_managers. Including your existing query would be a good idea too.